# Why doesn't Truffle's testing framework automatically retrieve fresh values of public state variables after every interaction with the contract?

Tags: solidity, truffle, javascript, testing

I have the following simple smart contract defined:

```
contract LoanApplication {

  struct Applicant {
    bytes32 ssn;
    bool hasApplied;

  }

  struct Loan {
    string loanID;
    uint applicantCount;
    uint256 rate;
    uint term;
  }

 mapping (address => Applicant) public applicants;

 Loan[] public loans;

 address public loansAdmin;

 constructor(string[] memory loanIDs) {

    loansAdmin = msg.sender;

   for (uint i=0; i < loanIDs.length; i++) {
        // Create Loan object and append to loans array
        loans.push(Loan({
            loanID: loanIDs[i],
            applicantCount:0,
            rate: 10,
            term: 30
            }));
    }
 
 }

 function receiveApplication(address applicant) external {
    require(
        msg.sender == loansAdmin, "Only administrator can receive application"
        );

     require(
        !applicants[applicant].hasApplied,
        "Applicant previously applied"
        );

    applicants[applicant].hasApplied = true;

 
   }

}
```

This is my Javascript test for it:

```
const LoanAppContract = artifacts.require("LoanApplication");

contract("LoanApplicationTest", accounts => {


    const loanIDs = ["Loan1", "Loan2", "Loan3"];


    beforeEach (async () =>  {
       loanApp = await LoanAppContract.new(loanIDs);
    });
     describe("initialization", () => {
        ...


      });



     describe("register application",() => {
        it("receive app",  async() => {


          let applicantAddr = accounts[1]; 
          console.log("applicantAddr=" + applicantAddr);

          let applicant = await loanApp.applicants(applicantAddr);


          assert.isTrue(!applicant.hasApplied);


          await loanApp.receiveApplication(applicantAddr, {from: accounts[0]});


          let applicantRefreshed = await loanApp.applicants(applicantAddr);

          //assert.isTrue(applicant.hasApplied);

          assert.isTrue(applicantRefreshed.hasApplied);


    });

  });

});
```

I am trying to test out the receiveApplication function in the contract.
The loans Administrator sets the `hasApplied` flag in the application object corr. to the address passed in to true

My question is for these lines:

```
// Obtain applicant 
let applicant = await loanApp.applicants(applicantAddr);

// Verify that hasApplied is set to false
assert.isTrue(!applicant.hasApplied);
```

Now call the receiveApplication function. The hasApplied flag is now set to true

```
 await loanApp.receiveApplication(applicantAddr, {from: accounts[0]});
```

My question is this:

Why does this test fail ?

I'm expecting

```
assert.isTrue(applicant.hasApplied)
```

to succeed, indicating that hasApplied is true, but it seems like the applicant reference is stale ?

Instead I have to do

```
let applicantRefreshed = await loanApp.applicants(applicantAddr);
assert.isTrue(applicantRefreshed.hasApplied);
```

for the test to succeed.
I'm fairly new to Solidity and Javascript - been a Python and Java developer to date.

Appreciate help to clarify this.

I’m running my test using truffle, thx

Comment: Your question is missing an important detail - which test framework and web3 library are you using?

Comment: I’m using truffle thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially because you are already using an abstraction layer that gives you what you need, when you need, giving you *fresh* values when called. It's up to the abstract instance of the contract (`loanApp` in your case) to work behind the scene, call the node via RPC to know the state and send back the result to you. And this is why you need `await` and you cannot use the value just in time.

The smart contract can be modified externally by the developer application/testing environment, so trying to keep a sort of *live sync* is not trivial. You can try [Drizzle](https://trufflesuite.com/drizzle/) for example to do that, but in any case, it's dedicated to the UI, not to the test and development phase.

Anyway, if you want a more succinct syntax for your case without the need to use many temp variables, you can write something like this:

```
let applicantAddr = accounts[1]; 
console.log("applicantAddr=" + applicantAddr);
assert.isTrue(!(await loanApp.applicants(applicantAddr)).hasApplied);
await loanApp.receiveApplication(applicantAddr, {from: accounts[0]});
assert.isTrue((await loanApp.applicants(applicantAddr)).hasApplied);
```

Comment: Ok this is helpful and informative. Thx for the more succinct code suggestion too